# Cypress with MeteorJS: user does not stay logged in

Tags: reactjs, meteor, cypress

Im trying to write E2E tests for my app, but first a user needs to be authenticated. This should not be a problem. Only a form needs to filled out and the login button should be pressed. As you can see in the image attached the user gets authenticated and can run fine through the first tests. However, the user gets logged out by itself at some point during the execution of the test functions.

When doing the tests manually the user never gets logged out automatically. I literally have no clue why this behaviour is happening.

Here are my tests:

```
 describe('RouteCard', function() {
  it('Renders Routes page', function() {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/routes')

    cy.contains('Public Routes')
  })

  it('Can login', function() {
    const testUsername = 'debtdrie'
    const testPassword = 'absenceearly-morning'

    cy.get('#loginform').within(() => {
      cy.get('[name="idcard"]')
        .type(testUsername)

      cy.get('[name="password"]')
        .type(testPassword)

      cy.get('.btn').click()
    })
    cy.wait(1000)
  })

  const getFavCount = user => user && user.profile && user.profile.favorites && user.profile.favorites.length

  it('Can favorite route', function() {
    let initialFavoriteCount
    cy.window().then(win => {
      const user = win.Meteor.user()
      initialFavoriteCount = getFavCount(user)
    })

    cy.get('.is-not-favorite > .ion-ios-heart-outline').first().click()
    cy.wait(1000)

    cy.window().then(win => {
      const user = win.Meteor.user()
      const newFavoriteCount = getFavCount(user)

      expect(initialFavoriteCount + 1).to.equal(newFavoriteCount)
    })

    cy.wait(1000)
  })

  it('Can unfavorite route', function() {
    let initialFavoriteCount
    cy.window().then(win => {
      const user = win.Meteor.user()
      initialFavoriteCount = getFavCount(user)
    })

    cy.get('.is-favorite > .ion-ios-heart').first().click()
    cy.wait(1000)

    cy.window().then(win => {
      const user = win.Meteor.user()
      const newFavoriteCount = getFavCount(user)

      expect(initialFavoriteCount - 1).to.equal(newFavoriteCount)
    })
  })
})
```

[image: cypress tests with MeteorJS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're doing is actually an anti-pattern. Do you try to login in first test and hope that your user will be logged-in in following tests as well. That's not supported in Cypress - **every test is executed on the fresh new environment**. That way you can easily isolate the problem and can be sure the failed test failed cuz of the local problem and not because of some issue which persisted from previous test. Read more about it [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Having-tests-rely-on-the-state-of-previous-tests). You'll have to login before every test again. Look into `beforeEach()`

```js
beforeEach(function() {
 // runs before each test in the block
})
```

Also, you described your login process as having cypress to really click the forms, right? Unless you're testing a login mask, you shouldn't do this either. **Try to login programmatically** in the background (send login request from cypress without clicking anything). Read more [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Having-tests-rely-on-the-state-of-previous-tests).